# wpa_supplicant and signal strength

Tags: wifi, gui, wpa-supplicant, wpa

I use `wpa_supplicant` to handle a connection to specific `SSID`. I added the `wpa_supplicant` to `default` `runlevel` in order to start it at the boot time.
I have this question however; Is it any program, script or even ncurses GUI to show me exact and live signal strength.
This is useful as it shows me if my location has poor reception or my ISP has low speed at each given time.
PS: I checked `iw` and its family like `iwlist` but they are not really what i want.

Answer (score 1):

It is little known feature, but `Conky` can be run in console mode with its variables describing network: http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html

You could edit any conkyrc and use `output_to_x` and `output_to_console` variables to have conky render text in console.

Also you could try `wifi-menu` (for network selection and control) and `wawemon` (nice wifi graphs). Both aplications work on wpa_suplicant.

While you might prefer bare-bones solution, `wicd` daemon has its own ncurses and cli interfaces.

Also aircrack-ng has `airmon`, thought because those tools used for hacking, they might not fit your needs.

Comment: using `wavemon -i wlp5s0` i get `wavemon: no wireless extensions found on 'wlp5s0'` .

Comment: any tool with the same functionality as `wavemon` but newer and no need for `kernel compatibility layer` ???